# How to get all the content of the website article in a facebook instant article?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I am using "**Facebook instant articles**" feature for my WordPress website.

The instant articles are being generated without any error, and I can see them while using the Facebook app. In the generated instant article only first five lines of the original article's content are displaying. The rest of the content from the article is coming as a hyperlink. Users need to click on READ MORE link which comes after five lines. The link will redirect the user to original link via the browser.

[image: Screenshot]

**Things I have tried:**

I have checked if there is any option for including all the text from an article in STYLE EDITOR in Facebook *page's publishing tools* section. But didn't find any option there.

If I disable Divi builder everything is working fine. When I enable builder plugin, read more (hyperlink) is coming.

**Some more information:**

I have not yet tried API option for generating instant articles.

I am using default style editor.

I am using official Facebook [instant articles for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/) plugin for generating instant articles.

I am not using RSS feed option.

I am using Divi Builder plugin.

**Question**: How to display all the content from the article in facebook instant article?

Comment: Which plugin do you use?

Comment: Hi @WizKid, I am using facebooks official [Instant Articles for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/) plugin